# stop mediaplayer sound when press back button in android studio!pls help me to find my mistake.thanks alot

Tags: android, loops, button

in my app exist two activity and a button . when user touch button in activity1 , app go to activity2 that three image with sound played Consecutively and repeat until user touch back button.
when user touch back button application go to activity1 .
The problem is that when the back button is pressed, it goes to the second activity, but there is no image displayed, and the broadcast sound is not interrupted, and it is constantly repeated, and the program loop does not come out.
I do not know where the program logic is wrong!
please guide me
my code is:

```
{
    public MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Button button;
    ImageView im;
    Context context;
    int current_img = 0;
    int current_aud = 0;
    boolean flag= false;

    int[] sounds={R.raw.anar,R.raw.ab,R.raw.abi};
    int[] images = { R.drawable.anar, R.drawable.water , R.drawable.abi};
    String[] texts={"انار","آب","آبی"};
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in backpress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
    }

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);

        im = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.anar);


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            public void run()
            {

                    textView.setText(texts[i]);
                    im.setImageResource(images[i]);
                    i++;

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, sounds[j]);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "in while", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mp.start();
                        j++;

                    if (j > sounds.length - 1) {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    if (i > images.length - 1) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);  //for interval...
            }


        };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. move the handler to class , and release it in onBackPressed()
2. try to change the onBackPressed():

   ```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "in backpress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        if(handler!=null){
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
   ```

Comment: Hi thanks alot but this change not solve my problem! When i press back button app ,Returns to the previous activity, but the playing sound is not cut off. How can I tell inside the Create method when the back button is pressed to mute the sound completely. Thanks if review my code and solve my problem.

Comment: add  remove  callback of handler @mojtaba

Comment: Excuse me , where exactly should I write Handler? Which class?

Comment: just move your    final Handler handler = new Handler();  from onCreate to the class @mojtaba

Comment: Thank you. This problem has been solved. Now I have a problem that there are two activities in the program. In the first activity, there are, for example, 26 buttons for the letters of the alphabet. When each letter is clicked, images related to that letter and their sounds are displayed on an activity or other page. When the back button is pressed, the program returns to the first activity.
How should I implement this logic?
Thanks for posting 

Comment: If this answer solves the problem, it is recommended to tick the tick and accept the answer .And if there is a different question, it is recommended to ask a new one and add some code. @mojtaba

Comment: hi,thanks alot. plz see this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68572654/16480784